# Backgroundservice and sending Requests

Tags: android, service, sms

I created a Backgroundservice where i want to send SMS in the Background when i press the power button for example.

This is my code for sending sms when i press the power button:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
 smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, "Ich brauche Hilfe! Hier ist mein aktueller Standort, kannst du mir helfen kommen?" + "\n" + "http://maps.google.com/?q=" + lat + "," + lon, null, null);
    return true;
       }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

What i want to ask is: Do i need to write this code into my Backgroundervice and start the Service in the MainActivty onKeyDown? or keep it in my MainActivity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sends SMS in Background when Power Button is pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569625/sends-sms-in-background-when-power-button-is-pressed)

Comment: This is not actually a duplicate. The question here is "ok, but having created a service to send messages in the background, does this code fragment block the UI thread? I think.

Comment: YOu can run this code on the UI thread, no problem. The method follows an Async pattern already based on the last two arguments to the method.